# Fridge vs freezer for short-term DNA storage – how long until freezer is better?

Tags: dna, dna-damage

I know keeping DNA products in the freezer (-20°C) is preferred for long-term storage, but the downside is that freeze-thawing can cause shearing/breaking of the DNA. For short-term storage the fridge (+4°C) may therefore be better. But how short is "short-term"? I'm working with many samples of DNA products in several steps over the course of a few weeks (extractions, checking concentrations, PCR, cleanups, gels), and I can only do a few samples at a time. Questions is what I should do with the others in the meantime. If I keep them in the fridge to avoid freeze-thawing, the end-result may be that the samples spend these few weeks totally in +4°C (except for when I'm processing them at room temperature). On the other hand, I could save quite a few freeze-thaw cycles by having them in the fridge, because I'm doing something with each sample every few days. On the third hand... I'm working with amplicons (400-600 bp), so having long, intact DNA fragments is not really that important to me. I should also add that my DNA extracts are in water, not TE buffer.

So, at what point would you put these samples in the freezer instead? If we would generalize, how long until the "break-even point", when the degradation in the fridge can be comparable to the degradation from one freeze-thawing cycle?

Comment: The concern for freeze-thaw cycles is a bit overblown, I think, but it's hard to generalize. TE probably helps stabilize DNA, but any nucleases present will strongly contribute to degradation. If you're really concerned, I would check for myself by putting a dummy sample at 4 C and checking stability on a gel or bioanalyzer.

Comment: https://openbiotechnologyjournal.com/contents/volumes/V7/TOBIOTJ-7-10/TOBIOTJ-7-10.pdf